# How to render a table from axios GET requests?

Tags: reactjs, redux, async-await, axios, react-hooks

I'm attempting to render a table of stats from an NBA API. I'm using redux to store the user's selected players and requesting the API through my Table component. I retrieve the stats appropriately however it ends up infinitely requesting the API. I know that me setting a hook within an asynchronous request will cause this behavior but I'm not sure of a workaround at the moment. I think this is a lifecycle error, should I try using useEffect and have the player object from the redux store in the dependency array? Any input would be great. I'll post the code below.

**Here's a screengrab of the behavior and console log when I log cData:** 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeaFB.jpg

**Table.js**

```
const DataTable = () => {
  const [completeData, setCompleteData] = React.useState([]);
  const players = useSelector(state => state.players);
  var cData = [];

  const search = async val => {
    try {
      const res = await axios(
        `https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?player_ids[]=${val}`
      );
      const responseData = res.data.data;
      console.log(responseData);
      return responseData;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>2019-2020 Season Averages</h3>

      <Table responsive>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Points</th>
            <th>Assists</th>
            <th>Rebounds</th>
            <th>Steals</th>
            <th>Blocks</th>
            <th>Turnovers</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(players).map(function(item, i) {
            var currentPlayerData = {};
            currentPlayerData = search(players[item])
              .then(result => {
                cData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                console.log(cData);
                setCompleteData(old => [...old, cData]);

                // setCurrentData(cData);
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          })}
          {completeData &&
            completeData.map(function(item, i) {
              console.log(item);
              return (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.pts}</td>
                  <td>{item.ast}</td>
                  <td>{item.reb}</td>
                  <td>{item.stl}</td>
                  <td>{item.blk}</td>
                  <td>{item.turnover}</td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach (assuming that you want to get data from NBA API as soon as your component loads).

When your table component loads, in `componentDidMount()` call a method for example call `this.getNBAdata()`in your action.js which will get the data from API. Once you receive the data in `.then()` you should dispatch an action with payload data to the reducer, which can we used by adding mapStatetoProps() your table component, so once you receive the data in your props variables it will reload/refresh that particular component and by the help of .map() you shall be able to display the data in table.

Action.js sample request:

```
export const getNBAData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {

Axios.get("http://nbadataendpoint.com")
  .then(response => {
    //you will get the data in response object
    dispatch({ type: 'YOUR_SUCCESS', payload: 'SOME_VALUE' });
  })
  .catch(error => {
      dispatch({ type: 'UNAUTHORISED', payload: 'SOME_VALUE'});
    }
  });
 }
};
```

Comment: Ok I like this. However I'm using functional components, so as being somewhat new to React I'm unsure how to use mapStatetoProps().

Comment: usually in redux, all async flow go through middlware such as redux-thunk and then to the reducers and then mapStateToProps. better if you read some of redux docs in function component useEffect is creating similar effect to componentDidMount

Comment: use connect method in your table component to use mapstatetoProps, here is the example:  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getNBAData })(TableComponent);

Comment: @mrbeans Ok so I've got the action/reducers set up per your suggestion however I think there's an issue in the action. I keep receiving this error: Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. Here is what my updated code looks like :

Comment: `import axios from "axios";
export const addPlayerData = name => {
  return function(dispatch) {
    console.log("Forming an axios request for: " + name);
    return axios
      .get(
        'https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?player_ids[]=${name}'
      )
      .then(response => {
        //you will get the data in response object
        console.log(response);
        dispatch({ type: "SUCCESS", name: name, obj: response.data.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        dispatch({ type: "UNAUTHORISED", payload: "SOME_VALUE" });
      });
  };
};
`

Comment: `React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("====Players has been updated: ");
    Object.keys(players).map(function(item, i) {
      console.log(item);
    });

    Object.keys(players).map(function(item, i) {
      playerAdd(addPlayerData());
    });
  }, [players, playerAdd]); `

Comment: I can see In action.js code  there seems to be typos. Instead of return function(dispatch) you should only use return  (dispatch) and return axios .get('url) it should be axios.get('url'). Please check action.js code in the answer you have written return 2 times.

Comment: I fixed up that code and now it works perfectly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad to help :)